# Data of Multiple related tables not shown in Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I am using .net core 2.2. When I run the following output is shown in the list of **FacultyInterestItem** with the **Faculty** or **Keywords** table data missing. Although the Faculties and Keywords classes are connected with the FacltyInterestItems 
   [image: Faculty Interest Items list with missing Faculty and Keyword Data]

The following is the razor page

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.FacultyInterestItems)
    {
        <tr>
 <td>     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)           
        </td>                
 <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Faculty.FacultyId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Keyword.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

The cs file of the Razor page having OnGetAsync() method where it connects and take data from **WebAPI**.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    List<FacultyInterestItems> facultyInterestItem = new List<FacultyInterestItems>();
    HttpClient client = _api.Initial();
    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/FacultyInterestItems");
    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        facultyInterestItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FacultyInterestItems>>(result);
    }
    List<Faculties> listOfFaculty = new List<Faculties>();
    res = await client.GetAsync("api/Faculties");
    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        listOfFaculty = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Faculties>>(result);
    }
    List<Keywords> listOfKeywords = new List<Keywords>();
    res = await client.GetAsync("api/Keywords");
    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        listOfKeywords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Keywords>>(result);
    }
    FacultyInterestItems = facultyInterestItem;
    Keywords = listOfKeywords;
    Faculties = listOfFaculty;

}
```

The procedure **OnGetAscyn()** in razor page cs file, gets data from API. Here is the get method in the controller of API that connects to the DB and fetch data.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<FacultyInterestItems>>> GetFacultyInterestItems()
{
    return await _context.FacultyInterestItems.ToListAsync();
}
```

Here is the model:

**The Faculties Table**

```
public partial class Faculties
{
    public Faculties()
    {
        FacultyInterestItems = new HashSet<FacultyInterestItems>();
        SuggestedKeywords = new HashSet<SuggestedKeywords>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FacultyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InsertDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FacultyInterestItems> FacultyInterestItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SuggestedKeywords> SuggestedKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

**The FacultyInterestItems tables:**

```
public partial class FacultyInterestItems
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? FacultyId { get; set; }
    public int? KeywordId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Faculties Faculty { get; set; }
    public virtual Keywords Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

**the Keywords table:**

```
public partial class Keywords
{
    public Keywords()
    {
        FacultyInterestItems = new HashSet<FacultyInterestItems>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Departments Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FacultyInterestItems> FacultyInterestItems { get; set; }
}
```

Data of Faculty and Keyword is not fetched from the DB. Please let me know the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `Include` method

```
 _context.FacultyInterestItems.Include(x => x.Faculty).Include(x => x.Keyword).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: I did this it gives error on this line facultyInterestItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FacultyInterestItems>>(result);  
                                                                                      
                    JsonSerializationException: Unexpected end when deserializing array. Path '[0].faculty.facultyInterestItems', line 1, position 207.

Comment: Solved! Thanks Martin, the problem is with my generated model, i removed this at it worked public virtual ICollection<FacultyInterestItems> FacultyInterestItems { get; set; } in the Faculties.cs